# Call RecyclerView adapter method inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have recently transferred my code from activity to fragment, however getting this error while trying to call public method "attachDatabaseReadListener()" of recycler view adapter inside fragment:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.example.digicube.RecyclerViewAdapter.attachDatabaseReadListener()' on a null object reference
```

Before moving to fragment i was able to call public methods of adapter by calling it like `adapter.publicMethod()` however it is not working in fragment now.

Here is my RecyclerView adapter's code:

```
import ...

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    ...

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Callback callback, Context context) {
        mCallback = callback;
        this.mContext = context;

        // ArrayList to hold task objects from Firebase database for recyclerViewAdapter
        mBrands = new ArrayList<>();

        // Initialize Firebase Components
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mBrandsDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("brands");
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.brand_layout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final TaskStructure taskStructure = mBrands.get(position);
        holder.mBrandNameTextView.setText(taskStructure.getBrandName());
        holder.mCategoryTextView.setText(taskStructure.getCategory());
        holder.mAvgUserRatingTextView.setText(String.valueOf(taskStructure.getAvgUserRating()));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ...
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Collections.sort(mBrands, TaskStructure.AverageUserRatingComparator);
        return mBrands.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mBrandNameTextView;
        private TextView mCategoryTextView;
        private TextView mAvgUserRatingTextView;
        private ImageView mBrandImageView;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mBrandNameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand_name);
            mCategoryTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category);
            mAvgUserRatingTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avg_user_rating);
            mBrandImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.brand_image);
        }
    }

    public void attachDatabaseReadListener() {
        if (mChildEventListener == null) {
            mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
               ...
            };
            mBrandsDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }
    }

}
```

and I am initiating it on onViewCreated method of fragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        recyclerViewBrands = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_brands);
        recyclerViewBrands.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()));

        brandsAdapter = new com.example.digicube.RecyclerViewAdapter(this, getActivity());
        recyclerViewBrands.setAdapter(brandsAdapter);
    }

    // Method call by activity on signed in
    public void attachListener(){
        brandsAdapter.attachDatabaseReadListener();
    }
```

Comment: Could you please share your RecycleView adapter's code and where you initialize your adapter into the fragment. ?

Comment: @NazmusSaadat updated

Comment: There is no `attachDatabaseReadListener()` call in the provided code. That's what's crashing. You'll need to add the code that contains that call, along with the complete stack trace.

Comment: @MikeM. sorry missed while copying to question updated now, however still looking for help.

Comment: No, not the method itself (though that's good to have). We need to see where you're calling that method; the `Fragment`'s code. And we need the complete stack trace, not just the first line.

Comment: @MikeM. got it working by calling it at the end of `onViewCreated()` method. Previously I was calling it on method `attachListener()` (updated in question) which was executing by activity before `onViewCreated()`, causing the error!. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by calling `attachDatabaseReadListener()` method at the end of onViewCreated() method in fragment. 
Previously I was calling it on public method `attachListener()` which was executing by activity before onViewCreated(), causing the error!

thanks [Mike M.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2850651/mike-m) for your comment which helped me understanding the problem.